# How to assign names to the bands in Dask.array when importing Geotiff files?

Tags: dask, python-xarray, geotiff

I am trying to import a Geotiff with multiple bands using Dask and xarray and the following code:

```
import xarray as xr
chunks = {'x': 15886, 'y': 2400, 'band': 1}
df= xr.open_rasterio('multiband.tif',chunks = chunks)
df
```

which df looks like:

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 6, y: 2400, x: 15886)>
dask.array<open_rasterio-b9dd4de67eb722145cdc7b5a3510e05e<this-array>, shape=(6, 2400, 15886), dtype=uint8, chunksize=(1, 2400, 15886), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int32 1 2 3 4 5 6
  * y        (y) float64 70.0 69.99 69.99 69.99 69.98 ... 60.01 60.01 60.01 60.0
  * x        (x) float64 -146.2 -146.2 -146.2 -146.2 ... -80.01 -80.0 -80.0
Attributes:
    transform:         (0.0041666666662862895, 0.0, -146.190219951, 0.0, -0.0...
    crs:               +init=epsg:4326
    res:               (0.0041666666662862895, 0.0041666666662862895)
    is_tiled:          0
    nodatavals:        (nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
    scales:            (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    offsets:           (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    AREA_OR_POINT:     Area
    TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE:  HEG-Modis Reprojection Tool  Nov 4, 2004
```

And the bands are stored in a Dask.array. I wonder how can I give names to each band (similar to "data variables" in xarray). Then for example I can get access to each band by:

```
df['band1name']
```

Currently what I'm doing to get access to the bands is something like:

```
df.isel(band=1)
```

which is not that intuitive.
Thanks

Comment: You can create your individual data arrays with the `isel(band=)`method and then construct/merge a new dataset out of them.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am doing right now, but it would be much nicer if there was a rename method.

Comment: I am confused on exactly what you hoping to be able to do? Do you want to change the band values from 1,2,3,4,5,6 to something else? Note, you can always use the .to_dataframe() method to convert from a xarray to pandas dataframe object.

Comment: I am not trying to change the band values. I just want to give names to each band. As I mentioned in the question instead of df.isel(band=1)  I want to be able to use df['band1_name'].

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to this for anyone else stumbling upon this issue in the Digital Earth Australia documentation (https://docs.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/Frequently_used_code/Opening_GeoTIFFs_NetCDFs.html).

We simply convert our dataarray to a dataset

```
ds = df.to_dataset('bands')
```

to get all bands as separate variables.

Afterwards, we rename the variables to the correct names:

```
ds = ds.rename({i + 1: name for i, name in enumerate(bandnames)}
```

The `i + 1` stems from the beginning of the indexing at 1 in bands and bandnames needs to be given.
If you download your GeoTiffs from GEE, you can get all bandnames in `ds.attrs['long_name']`.